# How do I set the tabbing order of controls in Android?

Tags: android, tabbing

You can move between fields with the track ball.
As the title says I am looking forward to know how to I set the tabbing order of controls in Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `android:nextFocusDown`, etc. See the "Focus Handling" section of [the documentation on Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).